# Bind values with AngularJS and Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to angularjs. Trying to code the Edit functionality of a single person record.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                    @Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.ID, new { @class = "form-control", ng_value="ID" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name, new { @class = "form-control", ng_value="Name" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Address, new { @class = "form-control", ng_value="Address" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Telephone, new { @class = "form-control", ng_value="Telephone" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatedata()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

  <script>

        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

        app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$http){

            $scope.updatedata = function () {
                alert($scope.Name);
                $http({ method: "post", url: "/Person/Edit", data: { id: $scope.ID, Name: $scope.Name, Address: $scope.Address, Telephone: $scope.Telephone } })
                .success(function () { alert("Success."); });

            }

        })

    </script>
```

When I click on the update button. $scope doesn't pass values to the server side Edit method. all the parameter values are null but actually, values do exist in Textboxes.

It looks like a conflict between AngularJS ng_value and the values loaded by Razor.

> For Ex: $scope.Name is undifined.

Comment: It is a weird concept using both Razor and AngularJS. Seeing as they both do roughly the same thing. Generally you would just have one or other and you'd still benefit just as much, if not more, than having them side by side. In my experience having them side my side has caused more issues than it has solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `ng-value`(one way binding) directive, place `ng-model` directive over your text-box to enable two way binding like `ng_model="Name"`. So any time changes occurs in text-box will reflect those changes in respective `ng-model` scope variable.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Telephone, 
   new { @class = "form-control", ng_value="Telephone", ng_model="Name" })
```

Answer (score 0):

ng_value does not bind your text box value with scope variable because it is one way binding instead of that use **ng_model** to bind your model data with angularjs controller scope.